The correct interpretation of a sentence such as “どうして謝る？”, not “謝っている”
I've always simply seen this sentence as “Why are you apologizing” without much thought but I'm suddenly given pause to wonder since normally one would use “謝っている” to mean “I'm apologizing” whereas “私が謝る” would typically be construed as a future tense statement as in “I'll be the one to go apologize to him.” so how is this taken with “どうして” when clearly not about the future? Does it mean “Why would you apologize?” for instance or does it still simply mean “Why are you apologizing?” and if so, what would be the difference with “どうして謝ってる？”


どうして謝って（い）る？

This is more likely to be a simple and specific question, because it refers to the ongoing event by -ている. It asks the reason for the specific event in front of you.

どうして謝る？

This can often be a rhetorical question, with the meaning of "you don't need to apologize", "it doesn't make sense for you to apologize", etc. Without -ている, it refers to a class of events generally, if the context indicates that the event has already happened.
It can still be a genuine question, to ask generally why, if it makes sense for the asking side to do so in the given context. (If it's asked immediately after the event has happened, it's usually not the time for a general question - that makes it more likely to be a rhetorical question.) For example, when the listener repeatedly apologizes in a way that makes you wonder why, the sentence fits.
The sentence can refer to a future event, as you say, again, if the context indicates that the event has not happened yet. For example, when the speaker and the listener are discussing whether to apologize to a third person, the sentence fits.

The difference is small, and they're typically interchangeable. But どうして謝る can sound like either:

The question is about the listener's intention
Someone is about to start or has just started their apology

On the other hand, どうして謝っている sounds like the speaker is seeking clarification about what's currently going on.

Grammatically, "どうして謝る？" could be "Why do you apologize?" or "Why would you apologize?" (depending on context).
"どうして謝ってる？" is "Why are you apologizing?"
It's worth noting, though, that "どうして謝る？" would often just be localized to "Why are you apologizing?", since "Why do you apologize?" is denotatively correct but its connotation is awkwardly mature in English (e.g. you don't expect a teenage girl to say "Why do you apologize?" in English. But it's totally fitting for a teenage girl in Japan to say "どうして謝る？").
